# How to convert timeseries to %M:%S.%f starting with 00:00.00

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the output of a 20 min measurement with unregular frequency (the timedelta between each measuring point is different) stored in a csv file with unix timestamps and the time in iso format:

```
unix_timestamp      time_iso                        data  
1602159331.000000   2020-10-08T12:15:31.00+00:00    10
1602159331.152680   2020-10-08T12:15:31.15+00:00    3
1602159331.222114   2020-10-08T12:15:31.22+00:00    5
...                 ...                             ...
1602160747.73929    2020-10-08T12:35:31.00+00:00    7
```

The actual time is irrelevant. The only relevant time is the timedelta compared to the first measuring point. So actually I want this data:

```
time(%M:%S.%f)     data
00:00.00           10
00:00.15           3
00:00.22           5
...                ...
00:20.00           7
```

Is there a nice way to convert the time to the desired format but keep the information that it is a time related data type?

Comment: `df['time'] = df['time_iso'] - df['time_iso'].iloc[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['time_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_iso'])

df['time_iso'] = df['time_iso'].sub(df['time_iso'].iat[0])
print (df)
   unix_timestamp               time_iso  data
0    1.602159e+09        0 days 00:00:00    10
1    1.602159e+09 0 days 00:00:00.150000     3
2    1.602159e+09 0 days 00:00:00.220000     5
3    1.602161e+09        0 days 00:20:00     7
```

Then for custom format use custom function:

```
df['time_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_iso'])


def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:05.2f}').format(int(minutes), seconds) 


df['time_iso'] = df['time_iso'].sub(df['time_iso'].iat[0]).apply(format_timedelta)
print (df)
   unix_timestamp  time_iso  data
0    1.602159e+09  00:00.00    10
1    1.602159e+09  00:00.15     3
2    1.602159e+09  00:00.22     5
3    1.602161e+09  20:00.00     7
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked as accepted, but I think now I lost the information that it is a time. I tried to plot the data with bokeh but without success. Is there a way to convert it to a type where I can have the desired format but keep the information that it is a time?

Comment: @19yc93 - Can you add `df['time_iso'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_iso'], format='%M:%S.%f').dt.time` after my solution?

Comment: Now we are getting closer. The format is now %H:%M:%S.%f, so it's `00:00:00.00  00:00:00.15  00:00:00.22  00:20:00.00`

Comment: @19yc93 Problem is time has always hours, so if need times cannot remove it.

Comment: @19yc93 If need `datetime.time` alway need HH:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS.f

Answer (score 0):

First import `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Cast unix timestamp to integer

```
ts = int(unix_timestamp)
```

Last, format timestamp

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # Printing this gives output as following HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS
```